# What is the purpose of the dtype argument in tensorflow_io.audio.AudioIOTensor

Tags: tensorflow

I've been trying to learn how to handle acoustic data with tensorflow. I've been working with data from the `Kaggle Challenge for Signal Processing - Z by HP Unlocked Challenge 3`. This website (https://blog.paperspace.com/audio-classification-with-deep-learning/) explains how to download that data given a Kaggle account and an API token.

I tried to read the `wav` files using `tensorflow_io.audio.AudioIOTensor`, which is documented here (https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/audio/AudioIOTensor) and explained in slightly more detail here (https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/audio). According to the documentation, `dtype` is an optional input parameter (i.e. if not specified, it is initially set equal to None), it is also an attribute of the `AudioIOTensor`, giving the `dtype` of the data.

However, I cannot determine how my choice of `dtype` affects anything. When I specify `dtype` as an input argument, it does not seem to effect my output, as I saw in the following notebook cell:

```
wav='XC9892-0.wav'
res1 = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor(wav)
res1a = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor(wav, dtype=tf.float32)
res1, res1a, res1.dtype, res1a.dtype

(<AudioIOTensor: shape=[154350      1], dtype=<dtype: 'int16'>, rate=44100>,
 <AudioIOTensor: shape=[154350      1], dtype=<dtype: 'int16'>, rate=44100>,
 tf.int16,
 tf.int16)
```

Although I set dtype to 'tf.float32' for the second tensor, it clearly did not change from int16.

However, if I don't specify dtype, then when I try to set up a preprocessing data pipeline using:

```
#Define preprocessing function
def preprocess(file_path, label): 
    wav = load_wav_16k_mono(file_path)
    wav = wav[:48000]
    zero_padding = tf.zeros([48000] - tf.shape(wav), dtype=tf.float32)
    wav = tf.concat([zero_padding, wav],0)
    spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(wav, frame_length=320, frame_step=32)
    spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)
    spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, axis=2)
    return spectrogram, label
    
# Create dataset
POS = os.path.join('data', 'temp', 'Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips')
NEG = os.path.join('data', 'temp', 'Parsed_Not_Capuchinbird_Clips')
pos = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(POS+'/*.mp3')
neg = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(NEG+'/*.mp3')

positives = tf.data.Dataset.zip((pos, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.ones(len(pos)))))
negatives = tf.data.Dataset.zip((neg, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.zeros(len(neg)))))
data = positives.concatenate(negatives)

#Preprocess
data = data.map(preprocess)
```

I get the this assertion error:

```
  AssertionError: dtype must be provided in graph mode
```

But, if `AudioIOTensor` is already aware of the `dtype` and won't let me change it using the `dtype` input argument, why is the `dtype` input needed?